# Xcode NSMutableArray not populating data from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, xcode5, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem with adding data to an NSMutableArray. I have a tableView and I store the cell text in an NSMutableArray. The tableView is user-populated, meaning that the user enters in what they would like to put on the tableView (to make lists, etc.). The problem I have is with storing the data they have entered. Here is my saving code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasksArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The variable "tasks" is the NSMutableArray. The above code happens right after the user presses the done button on the keyboard and the keyboard text is added to the "tasks" NSMutableArray. There does not seem to be any problem here because I have debugged and found that everything saves properly.

In my viewDidLoad:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"tasksArray"]];

if ([self.tasks count] == 0) {

    NSLog(@"Array is 0");
    self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

else {

    NSLog(@"Array is > 0");
    self.tasks = [[NSMutable array] alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"tasksArray"]];
}
```

Now the above code is where I want the data to be loaded onto the array which populates the tableView. The error I get is a NSRangeException, index 0 beyond bounds of empty array. The problem seems to be with the NSMutableArray "tasks" and trying to fill it with the saved data. My goal is to have the "tasks" array populated with the data stored on NSUserDefaults under the key "tasksArray" if the user has previously entered any data. If not, and the tableView should be empty, then I want the "tasks" array to be created.

If any help could be given as to what is wrong with my code or provide a different method of getting a result that would help a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using these If else condition. Just use

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if(!self.tasks)
    self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"tasksArray"]];
else
    [self.tasks addObjectsFromArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"tasksArray"]];
```

Now you can place the check, where you want

```
if([self.tasks count]){
}
else{
}
```

Comment: Yea same problem. For some reason NSMutableArray doesn't want to take the NSUserDefaults data. The error is index 0 is out of bounds for an empty array. So it must mean that the data never gets passed to the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

objectForKey returns a generic object. You know it's an array, but NSMutableArray does not recognize it as such. Use either:

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults arrayForKey:@"tasksArray"]];
```

or

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)[defaults objectForKey:@"tasksArray"]];
```